# Por qué laravel no me reconoce la validación image

Tags: php, laravel

Me sale un error de mime type guesser,solo es en imagen, tipo file en el formulario, por que puede ser?

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title'       => 'min:8|max:250|required|unique:articles',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'content'     => 'min:60|required',
            'imagen'      => 'image|required' // *** Error acá
        ];
    }
```

Comment: podrías agregar el mensaje de error mas detallado?

Answer (score 1):

Es un error sencillo, cuándo defines la norma para `imagen` no tienes que poner `image` en su definición por lo que la solución es simplemente eliminar ese tag:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'       => 'min:8|max:250|required|unique:articles',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'content'     => 'min:60|required',
        'imagen'      => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con el siguiente cambio:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title'       => 'min:8|max:250|required|unique:articles',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'content'     => 'min:60|required',
        'image'       => 'required|mimes:png,jpg' // extensiones aceptadas
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta verificar si cuentas con esto:

**agrega enctype="multipart/form-data" a tu formulario**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**En tu validación dejarlo de esta forma**

```
'imagen' => 'required | mimes:jpeg,jpg,png | max:1000',
```

Answer (score -1):

puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
'imagen' => 'mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'
```